# Issue while invoking a class and storing data into it c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class like this

```
public class basic
{
    public bool Success { get; set; } = false;
    public string Message { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
public class ServiceResponse<T>:basic
{
    public T? Data { get; set; }
    
}
public class ServiceResponse2<T> : basic
{
    public T?[] Data { get; set; }
}
```

And I invoke it in my controller like this

```
    ServiceResponse2<string> response = new ServiceResponse2<string>();
    response.Success = true;
    response.Message = "success";
    response.Data[0] = filename;
    response.Data[1] = outname;
```

when I do, I get runtime error in my lastline as: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I hovered on top of Data variables and the values were null. Can I know what I'm missing here? Apologies if its a dumb doubt

Comment: FYI - You dont need `ServiceResponse2` as you can create an instance of `ServiceResponse` with an array type argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `Data` is an array, and this is never initialized to an object. You need to initialize it, for example:

```
response.Data = new string[]{filename, outname};
```

Or

```
public T?[] Data { get; set; } = new T[2];
```

However, I would be careful with using an array like this. What does `Data` means? How should it be used? Why can I change it however and whenever I want? How is it related to the other properties? Does a specific index have some special meaning? Does it promise to hold some specific number of items?

If this is intended to be used for requests to some type of service it is normal to use some form of *serialization* to convert objects to data. And this is normally done fairly close to the communication layer, so that most of the code can handle typed objects, and only a small part need to handle bits and bytes.